# Error when deploying the artifact to Artifactory from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am getting error in Jenkins at final step of build.

Error is:Failed to deploy artifacts, could not transfer artifact.
Failed to transfer file *Artifactory URL*.
Return code is 400 -> bad request.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project :

Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact from/to snapshots (*Artifactory URL*): Failed to transfer file: *Artifactory URL*/project.jar.

Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request. -> [Help 1]

Please let me know what may cause this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happen if you run the maven-deploy from the command line of the Jenkins instance where is running the job? If you got the same issue it's a connectivity problem between Jenkins environment and JFrog Artifactory env

Comment: Is it working using JFrog API with curl command?

Comment: can you deploy manually from the machine without Jenkins ? need some more info to understand

Comment: Thanks ivoruJavaBoy,  saurabh14292, Mor Lajb for giving me your valuable suggestions. This issue is happening in the rare cases, but as ivoruJavaBoy sir said, it's a connectivity issue. Because it worked fine twice after this issue. But will keep posted once finding exact reason which caused this. Also will execute this build using Shell in Jenkins and let you know. Thanks